# Texture painting on a filled section applies it to all previous fills

Tags: texturing

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to Blender, and I'm
m trying to fill in and paint over some holes on a model I created with UAV photogrammetry, but I'm not having much luck.

Currently, to fill in the hole I -

1 - select all the surrounding vertices and press F.

2 - go to face and then triangulate, so I can sculpt the shape after.

3 - UV unwrap

4 - place the cursor somewhere which has a similar texture I want to
   clone

5 - Use texture paint to clone stamp the texture over the
   filled hole.

The problem starts when I've filled in multiple holes - It starts applying the exact same texture to all the previous filled holes/faces at the same time.

Why would it do this and how can i turn it off?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Screenshots attached

[image: Original hole in mesh]
[image: Filled in with F after selecting vertices]
[image: After UV Unwrap]

[image: Texture painted using clone stamp]

One of the holes I need to fill
Filled in with "F" after selecting vertices
After UV Unwrap
Texture painted using clone stamp
So if i repeated that process to fill in another hole, and clone stamp some texture over the top of it, the original one starts to get filled in with the same colours. Large parts of my model also get covered too in the same textures

I think what's happening is that i'm actually painting textures onto the original model textures? I don't know how to stop this though... all i want to do is colour in the face of a hole i filled.

Comment: It must have to do with your unwrap, some islands must overlap, so when you paint on one, it paints on another...

Comment: All I wanted to do was cover up random holes in the mesh and paint over them, am I even correct in the way I'm doing this? I thought pressing F to fill would literally just creat a simple polygon that I could paint over, but that didn't even work until I unwrapped it. I'm not even sure what an island is?

Comment: hard to tell without your file, or even some screenshots

Comment: I've edited my original post with screen shots if it helps.
Thanks